# Sort by date in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql

I receive datatable from SQL with many columns, but one column is datetime:

```
SELECT 
...
  , FORMAT([NoteDate] , 'dd/MMM/yyyy  h:mm tt' , 'en-US') AS [NoteDate]
FROM ...
```

So I receive it in DataGridView and try to format this column (as other questions suggest).

```
 dgvCallLogNotes.Columns["NoteDate"].HeaderText = "Date";
 dgvCallLogNotes.Columns["NoteDate"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "M/d/yyyy";
 dgvCallLogNotes.Columns["NoteDate"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

But when I try to sort it with column click it just sorting wrong. I think it is sorting by string.

[image: Evidence]

Comment: The `DataGridView` is perfectly capable of sorting dates properly.  Your SQL statement is converting to string which has consequences. Dates do not have a format, so just select it and use the Cell Style set to control how it is shown to the user (format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your sql as

```
SELECT 
  ...
  , [NoteDate]
FROM ...
```

And I believe the rest will work out ok. I'd even go as far as not setting a cell style to format the date; let it get the default from the regional settings of the computer it's running on, that way the user gets control of how he likes to see his dates (especially with m/d/y which can easily be misinterpreted as d/m/y)

Comment: How can I display same date format? I try: `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` , but I get month with number instead I.E: Jan, Sep etc...

Comment: I also try `"dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`  but it display month complete, I mean: Jaunary, September instead desire result: Jan, Sep

Comment: Use 3 letters MMM - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings